# Automapper doesn't work after upgrade from v7 to v9

Tags: c#, automapper, asp.net-core-2.0

With Automapper v7 i used this syntax:

```
res.Add(new AsseverazioneResource()
{
    FILEFIRMATO = Mapper.Map<PRAT_DOC_FILES, FileResource>(prat_doc?.PRAT_DOC_FILES.FirstOrDefault())
});
```

I just upgraded to v9 but i got an error on this line

> An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or
>   property

What changes are needed?

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/9.0-Upgrade-Guide.html

Comment: The error message appears to be incomplete. Didn't it refer to the specific property it's talking about? It would make sense to tell us the whole message. But yeah...see the upgrade guide link for a fairly simple explanation of why it's not working. When you upgrade things, it's a good idea to check the breaking changes _before_ you upgrade, so you can be prepared and plan how much time you might need to spend altering your code as a result. Then you can decide whether now is a good time to upgrade or not.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you.
I read the section about upgrading and the static API and I change my code to solve the problem

Comment: For the benefit of others reading in future, it would make a much better answer if you provided the updated version of the code.